# How to find if Electron app is a MAC or MAS Build?

Tags: macos, electron, electron-builder, mac-app-store

Is there a way to have an `is-MAS` for Mac Store builds in Electron? I tried looking through the package.json or even a build flag but no luck as of yet. I want to be able to have conditional content that's based on where the user downloads an electron app (Mac Store, Website, etc.).

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [process.mas](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/process#processmas-readonly) property at run time to test whether an app has been specifically built for the Mac App Store:

> `process.mas` *Readonly*
>
> A `Boolean`. For Mac App Store build, this property is `true`, for other
> builds it is `undefined`.

So, a simple `isMAS` function could be defined as:

```
function isMAS()
{
    return process.mas || false;
}
```